# How to return a Chainlink API Call to another contract?

Tags: solidity, oracles, chainlink

I need to call a function that returns the uint value requested by the oracle from another contract function.

I am trying the next... but I think I am going by the bad way. Any solution for that?

**The Caller contract code:**

```
pragma solidity 0.5.1;
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED

contract ETHPriceContract{ function getETHPrice() public view returns(bytes32);} 

contract CallerPriceRequest{
    
    uint256 public price;

    ETHPriceContract internal ETHPriceOracle;
 
    function initETHPrice(address ETHPriceAddress) public {
        ETHPriceOracle = ETHPriceContract( ETHPriceAddress );
    }
    
    function getETHPrice() public{
        ETHPriceOracle.getETHPrice();
    }
    
    function CallerFulfill(bytes32 _requestId, uint256 _price) public{
        price = _price;
    } 
}
```

**The Oracle requester contract code:**

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;

import "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/develop/evm-contracts/src/v0.5/ChainlinkClient.sol";

// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED

contract CallerPriceRequest{ function CallerFulfill(bytes32 _requestId, uint256 _price) public; }

contract ChainlinkRequestETHPrice is ChainlinkClient {
    
    address public CallerAddress = 0x5592675bf651ED82E30F78D5ebAfb1f7F5D851c7;
    uint256 public price;
    
    address private oracle;
    bytes32 private jobId;
    uint256 private fee;
    
    CallerPriceRequest internal Caller;
    
    constructor() public {
        Caller = CallerPriceRequest( CallerAddress );
        setPublicChainlinkToken();
        oracle = 0x2f90A6D021db21e1B2A077c5a37B3C7E75D15b7e;
        jobId = "29fa9aa13bf1468788b7cc4a500a45b8";
        fee = 0.1 * 10 ** 18; // 0.1 LINK
    }


    function getETHPrice() public returns (bytes32 requestId){
        Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(jobId, CallerAddress, Caller.CallerFulfill.selector);
        req.add("get", "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=USD");//{"USD":1797.12}
        req.add("path", "USD");
        req.addInt("times", 100);
        return sendChainlinkRequestTo(oracle, req, fee);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `buildChainlinkRequest` takes 3 parameters:

1. JobId
2. Callback Address
3. Function to callback to

Add your caller contract to be the callback contract. Like so:

In the calling contract, pass the address of the callback address and the callback function. You could also just hardcode the addresses in the calling contract.

```js
function getETHPrice() public{
        ETHPriceOracle.getETHPrice(address(this), this.CallerFulfill.selector);
    }
```

Then, use those parameters in the calling function:

```js
 function getETHPrice(address callBackContract, bytes4 functionSelector) public returns (bytes32 requestId){
        Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(jobId, callBackContract, functionSelector);
// code here
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Patrick. Works in basics. How can I send parameters to the "CallerFulfill()" from the caller "getETHPrice() "?

Comment: What are you trying to send? typically the chainlink node is going to be the one calling that function.

Comment: I need to request the ETHPrice from Caller and send my equivalent token amount to an address (msg.sender) and a fee amount to other address sent to the getETHPrice(address) function. I want to make all in one call.

Comment: In your `function getETHPrice() public{
        ETHPriceOracle.getETHPrice(address(this), this.CallerFulfill.selector);
    }` function, you can just pass more parameters to the callee contract, and have that function pass variables to the fulfill function.