# buildChainlinkRequest function of Chainlink is not working properly

Tags: solidity, remix, chainlink, oracles

The buildChainlinkRequest [line no 47](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/develop/contracts/src/v0.8/ChainlinkClient.sol) takes 3 parameters:

1. JobId
2. Callback Address
3. Function to callback to

I have smartcontract1 and smartcontract2. The below mentioned function is inside smartcontract2

```
function requestVolumeData(string memory _jobId, string memory addrsss, address callBackContract, bytes4 functionSelector) external returns (bytes32 requestId) {
   
    Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(
        stringToBytes32(_jobId),
        callBackContract,
        functionSelector
    );

    req.add("publicKey", addrsss);
    return sendChainlinkRequest(req, fee);
}
```

Code inside smartcontract1 given below,

```
interface OracleInterfacehere{
 function requestVolumeData(string memory _jobId, string memory addrsss, address callBackContract, bytes4 functionSelector) external returns (bytes32) ;
}


 function requestingdataFromOracle(string memory _jobId, string memory addrsss, address _smartcontract2) public  {
      OracleInterfacehere OracleOwnerGuard = OracleInterfacehere(_smartcontract2);
      OracleOwnerGuard.requestVolumeData(_jobId, addrsss,address(this), this.fulfill.selector);
 }

  function fulfill(
    bytes32 _requestId,
    bool _status
) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId) {
    status = _status;
}
```

What I am expecting is as smartcontract1 call "requestVolumeData" (inside smartcontract2) function, the oracle will send data back to "fulfill" function of smartcontract1.
But this is not working as expected

Note :  I have followed this approach(Mentioned in the answer by Patrick) [StackExchange question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/101331/how-to-return-a-chainlink-api-call-to-another-contract)

Comment: To clarify, are you saying in  `smartcontract1` if you pass through `address(this)` and `this.fulfill.selector` into your call of `smartcontract2`'s `buildChianlinkRequest` that things are working? 

This sounds like the proper way to format the request.

Comment: No, in smartcontract1 if i pass through address(this) and this.fulfill.selector into my call of smartcontract2's buildChianlinkRequest that things is not working. BUT, if I write these arguments in smartcontract2 buildChianlinkRequest itself, then its working fine

Comment: Could you update the question with the code you are using that isn't working

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: A couple more things to check.
1. Make sure both SmartContract1 and SmartContract2 have the necessary imports and are inheriting from the ChainlinkClient contract.
2. You mention `requestVolumeData` but are calling `requestVolumeDataNext` is that on purpose?

Comment: You may also want to look at the transaction on the block explorer to see what data is being passed when calling the fulfill function.

Additionally, the fulfill function would only have the requested and status available to it, is that what you are expecting?

Comment: yes, inheriting chainlinkclient in both. Its requestVolumeData only.Checked the explorer, it is having only requestId and status. What else could be the reason?

Comment: If inside smartcontract2(sc2), requestVolumeData have address(this) (of sc2) and this.fulfill.selector (of sc2), then things works fine. but because I am passing it from smartcontract1 then only the fulfill function (of sc1) is not receiving data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(
        stringToBytes32(_jobId),
        callBackContract,
        functionSelector
 );
```

This function is present in the ChainlinkClient contract that you would be using  but this is not the issue in the code.

When you call the function `sendChainlinkRequest` which is also present in the same contract and is the problem.

This functions body actually saves the address from which this function is actually called

```
bytes memory encodedRequest = abi.encodeWithSelector(
      ChainlinkRequestInterface.oracleRequest.selector,
      SENDER_OVERRIDE, // Sender value - overridden by onTokenTransfer by the requesting contract's address
      AMOUNT_OVERRIDE, // Amount value - overridden by onTokenTransfer by the actual amount of LINK sent
      req.id,
      address(this),
      req.callbackFunctionId,
      nonce,
      ORACLE_ARGS_VERSION,
      req.buf.buf
    );
```

Comment: Should i override it to "req.callbackAddress"? I thought security is a big concern while updating the chainlink smart contract.

Comment: If I'm understanding Lokesh the overrides would need to be the values for SC1. 

"This functions body actually saves the address from which this function is actually called"

You'll need to pass in the proper address and callback. Can you share more of the code to show where you are passing the req in?

Comment: @RichardG i have added more lines of code. Also please note I am following exactly the same approach mentioned here [same question asked here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/101331/how-to-return-a-chainlink-api-call-to-another-contract)

Comment: @RichardG even if i hardcode the value of callBackContract(address of smartcontract1) and pass it to requestVolumeData function of smartcontract2, then also its not working.

Comment: I have a smart contract built where I save the contract address as well as the callbackFunction signature while making the request. 
`requestDetails[requestId] = RequestContractDetails({
   responseContract: callerContract,
   responseFunctionId: callbackFunctionId
 });`

And in the fulfil function:
`address callerAddress = requestDetails[requestId].responseContract;
bytes4 callbackFunctionSignature = requestDetails[requestId].responseFunctionId;
(bool success, ) = callerAddress.call(abi.encodeWithSelector(callbackFunctionSignature, requestId, data));`

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to hear that the buildChainlinkRequest function is not working properly. Have you tried restarting the application or checking the logs to see if there are any errors? If you are still having trouble, please reach out to the Chainlink support team for more assistance.

Comment: yes i have restarted the system. no error logs. The only issue is that the "fulfill" function in smartcontract1 is not giving the result even after everything runs fine. If inside smartcontract2(sc2), requestVolumeData have address(this) (of sc2) and this.fulfill.selector (of sc2), then things works fine. Also I am exactly following the answer mentioned [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/101331/how-to-return-a-chainlink-api-call-to-another-contract) . not sure whats the issue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Can you remove the `recordChainlinkFulfillment()` modifier from the `fulfill()` function? One thing this modifier limits is who can call the function. When you call `sendChainlinkRequest`, it adds the oracle contract to the allow list.

I believe the issue is that SC2 knows about the address, but SC1 does not.

If you do this, anyone can call `fulfill()`. If you need to limit that, you could hardcode the oracle address or pass it through from SC2.